# How can you get Facebook to allow you more than 5000 friends?

Tags: facebook, friends

Facebook maxes out your friends at 5000.  Is there some way to get around this without just creating a second page?

Note: I'm not even close, but I have friends who have maxed out and have to kluge other accounts to try and manage things.

Comment: I suggest that your friends that have reached the 5000 limit might be trying to solve the wrong problem. It would be easier to re-define what is meant by a Facebook ‘friend’. If, for example, they deleted any friends from the 5000 that they haven’t either seen or spoken to in the last twelve months, then they’d probably create ample headroom for new ‘friends’.

Comment: @Mike, some have that problem and are just gregarious, some just got famous, and want to be able to send messages to a large group of people.

Comment: Perhaps Twitter is a more appropriate medium for those folks who wish to broadcast to over 5000.

Comment: @Mike, maybe, but hard to post real messages there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option would be to create a fan page for yourself and use that.  Fan pages have no limit to the amount of  "fans"

Comment: I think this is currently the only option other than creating new personal accounts for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://blog.socialpeople.nl/post/4025025806/facebookpagemigration) explains how to migrate your friends to a fan page.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Please don't just post links as an answer because if they break then this answer is pretty useless. Please edit your answer to include the relevant and/or important information and keep the link for reference. Thanks